# Wildfly/Jboss Docker Cluster using Docker-compose

Tags: docker, jboss, wildfly, docker-compose, mod-cluster

I am new to Wildly and Docker

I am trying to build a test cluster of wildfly.

I am using docker compose for orchestration.
Following is my docker-compose.yml file

```
node:  
  image: wildfly-mgmt  
  links:  
    - lb:lb  
lb:  
  image: wildfly-cluster-httpd  
  ports:  
   - "9090:80"
```

After running docker-compose up
I can not see the nodes in the mod cluster Management page.
http://localhost:9090/mod_cluster_manager
It is blank, somehow mod_cluster manager not able to see the nodes...

Docker file for mod cluster:

```
FROM fedora:latest  

RUN yum -y update  
RUN yum -y install httpd mod_cluster  
RUN yum clean all  

RUN sed -i 's|LoadModule proxy_balancer_module|# LoadModule proxy_balancer_module|' /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-proxy.conf  

ADD mod_cluster.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_cluster.conf  

EXPOSE 80  

CMD ["/sbin/httpd", "-DFOREGROUND"]
```

Mod_cluster.conf

```
LoadModule slotmem_module       modules/mod_slotmem.so  
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so  
LoadModule advertise_module     modules/mod_advertise.so  
LoadModule manager_module       modules/mod_manager.so  


<IfModule manager_module>  
  Maxhost 100  
  ServerName localhost  
  <VirtualHost *:80>  


    <Directory />  
      Require all granted  
    </Directory>  


    <Location /mod_cluster_manager>  
      SetHandler mod_cluster-manager  
      Require all granted  
    </Location>  


    KeepAliveTimeout 60  
    ManagerBalancerName mycluster  
    EnableMCPMReceive On  
    ServerAdvertise On  


  </VirtualHost>  
</IfModule>
```

I can see the servers running. 
`> Docker ps` command shows the two containers

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
b613166f4236        wildfly-mgmt            "/opt/jboss/wildfly/b"   18 hours ago        Up 18 hours         8080/tcp               dockercomposecluster_node_1
963a728bae70        wildfly-cluster-httpd   "/sbin/httpd -DFOREGR"   18 hours ago        Up 18 hours         0.0.0.0:9090->80/tcp   dockercomposecluster_lb_1
```

I can see the servers running from the console log

```
node_1  | 19:43:23,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
node_1  | 19:43:23,828 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
node_1  | 19:43:23,829 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 75208ms - Started 331 of 577 services (393 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

But the Mod-CLuster_manager is not able to see the nodes. Can anyone please point out what is wrong here? I am really new to this.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging you can do `docker exec -it containername bash` -it for interactive terminal. This should put you inside the container. From there can you do `telnet <containername> <port>` (you probably have to install telnet first) - or `docker inspect <containername>` the container you want to see and use its IP.
If you can't telnet, have you tried starting them on the same docker network?